# How can I apply styles to a label for a selected radio button

Tags: html, css, forms

Is it possible to style an active label with just CSS using the following markup:

```
<label class="inputOption" for="1"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="1" /><span class="aText">Option 1</span></label>
```

I want to add some background styles to the label once the radio inside is selected. Prefer not to use javascript. It is for mobile so it doesn't have to work on older browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this your can use CSS :checked property for this. Write like this:

```
#one{
    position:relative;
}
#one:checked + span{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:-20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    background-color: #aa2233;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/5TxyJ/5/

Comment: Tnx! That comes close to the way I want it. I googled a little and found out there is no css way to select the parent element (in this case the label). That would have been easier for me to style. This comes close enough tho :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you should add also a second class, let`s say "active" to the label, **only** when the radio button is selected:

```
<style type="text/css">
    label.active {
      background-color: #aa2233;
    }
</style>
<label class="inputOption active" for="1"><input type="radio" name="radio1" id="1" /><span class="aText">Option 1</span></label>
```

[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/5TxyJ/).

Comment: But how would I add the active class to the label of the selected radio button? I know how with javscript, but thats what i'm trying to avoid :)